# How can I find the relative xpath of anything that i click page (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, xpath

I have a page, and I want to use javascript to get the relative xpath of any element that I click on page..
but this code doesn't seems to work. How can i use this code to give me the relative xpath?

```js
function getElementXPath(elt, theClass) {
  var path = "";
  for (; elt && elt.nodeType == 1; elt = elt.parentNode) {
    idx = getElementIdx(elt);
    xname = elt.tagName;
    if (idx > 1) xname += "[" + idx + "]";
    path = "/" + xname + path;
  }

  return path;
}

function getElementIdx(elt) {
  var count = 1;
  for (var sib = elt.previousSibling; sib; sib = sib.previousSibling) {
    if (sib.nodeType == 1 && sib.tagName == elt.tagName) count++
  }

  return count;
}
document.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
  document.querySelector("#xpath").value = getElementXPath(e.target);

  alert(e.target.this.id + getElementXPath(e.target));
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use clientX/clientY on the event object emitted on click in the document. Here's a handle little function you can use:

```
const getCursorPosition = event => {
  return { 
    x: event.clientX,
    y: event.clientY
  }
}

window.addEventListener('click', e => {
  const position = getCursorPosition(e)
  console.log('click position: ', position)
})
```